# Need help in understanding Application.Evaluate

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an Excel VBA Newbie and I'm just trying to understand this code below.

I'm primarily struggling to understand the evaluate function, even though I have read it online.

I would appreciate if somebody could translate the code in plain English if possible, but of course any help is welcomed! :)

```
 For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "A").Value <> Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(LastRow, "B")).Address _
        & "=" & Cells(i, "B").Address & "," & Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).Address & "))") Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `Evaluate` just executes an Excel worksheet formula and returns the result.  Try using `Debug.Print` to send the argument passed to `Evaluate` to the Immediate pane - that is the formula being evaluated.  If you add an example output to your question it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Looks like your formula is an array formula to calculate the maximum corresponding value in ColA for each value in ColB and remove rows which don't have that value.  http://www.contextures.com/excelminmaxfunction.html

Comment: @TimWilliams Appreciate your comments too Tim!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what `Application.Evaluate` does, you need to understand that `Application` is referring to `Excel` itself, so `Evaluate` essentially boils down to a way to tap into Excel's expression evaluation engine.

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SUM(2, 2)") ' prints 4
```

There's a shorthand notation for it:

```
Debug.Print [SUM(2, 2)] ' also prints 4
```

It's rather slow though, so avoid it if you can. Excel has a rich object model that includes things like `Application.WorksheetFunction`, which lets you programmatically invoke worksheet functions such as `MAX` and `VLOOKUP` and almost everything you could possibly want to *evaluate*.

`Evaluate` doesn't just compute worksheet functions - it resolves expressions you would type into Excel's formula bar. For example:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=A1")
Debug.Print [A1]
```

Both print the content of cell A1. An interesting thing is that it returns types you can work with in VBA code, not just values:

```
Debug.Print TypeName([A1]) ' prints "Range"
```

Note that [as Tim Williams correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220183/need-help-in-understanding-application-evaluate/48220846?noredirect=1#comment83423330_48220846), `Application.Evaluate` always works off whichever sheet is currently active (and implicit references to `ActiveSheet` are a very common source of bugs!); if you need to `Evaluate` something, better do it off a specific `Worksheet` object, with e.g. `Sheet1.Evaluate` - that will return the expected result regardless of what sheet is active.

As for what your code does, that's a bit beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Worth adding that the evaluation *context* when using worksheet formulas with `Application.Evaluate` is the ActiveSheet.  This can lead to unexpected results if you're not careful.  There is also a `WorkSheet.Evaluate` form which uses the context of the qualifying worksheet object.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the input, seems to answer to my question sufficiently. I know it seems kind of like a no brainer question I'm really just a newbie ^^" Thanks so much!!