# Calculate new column values in excel-tables

Tags: excel, vba, calculated-columns, excel-tables

I have an excel-table and want to calculate a new column with values based on two columns of the table in VBA.
This is my code:

```
Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects("WPDE").ListColumns.Add(1).Name = "distance"
Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects("WPDE").ListColumns("distance").DataBodyRange.Formula _
    = "=(([@[UTM X]]-$D$2)^2+([@[UTM Y]]-$E$2)^2)^0.5/1000"
Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects("WPDE").ListColumns("distance").DataBodyRange.Value _
        = Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListColumns("distance").DataBodyRange.Value
```

In D2 and E2 are coordinates of the center and the formula calculates the distance of the coordinates in column "UTM X" and "UTM Y" from the center.

The code does what I want, but it is cumbersome to write the formula in the column first and then write the values in the column. Moreover I can't use variables I only have calculated in my VBA macro in the formula.

How can I calculate the new column in one step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *How can I calculate the new column in one step?* To be honest, your code is pretty good like this and doing formulations and then pasting as values it's a pretty common way. Anyways, if you want to do it in a single line of code, check [Evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220183/need-help-in-understanding-application-evaluate) And also maybe [WorksheetFunction object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction)

Comment: I too think this ist the best method - except I would use a `With`-statement: `set colDistance = . listojects...add` and then `With colDistance` ... `.name = "distance" ... `With .databodyrange`... `.Formula= ...` This reduces the "code noise" and increases readability.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried Evaluate, but I'm afraid it doesn't work for this usecase.

Comment: @Ike, I don't have practice using With-Statements, but do you mean like this:
`Set colDistance = Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects("WPDE").ListColumns.Add(1)
With colDistance
        .Name = "Distance"
        .DataBodyRange.Formula = "=(([@[UTM X]]-$D$2)^2+([@[UTM Y]]-$E$2)^2)^0.5/1000"
        .DataBodyRange.Value = Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Distance").DataBodyRange.Value
    End With`

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

For using the With-statement

```vb
Dim lcDistance As ListColumn
Set lcDistance = Workbooks(wbname_WPDE).Worksheets(1).ListObjects("WPDE").ListColumns.Add

With lcDistance
    .Name = "distance"
    With .DataBodyRange
        .Formula = "=(([@[UTM X]]-$D$2)^2+([@[UTM Y]]-$E$2)^2)^0.5/1000"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you!
Do you have an idea for me, how I can use variables (defined in the macros) instead of $D$2 and $E$2? My trick would be to write the variable value in the table, then refer to it and then delete the values, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Did you think of using names for D2 and E2? - then you can put then name of the cell within the formula

Comment: D2 and E2 are only placeholders here. In the real usecase they come out of another workbook. And yes, there they have names, but I don't think I can adress them in the Formula (without using the workbook name, which changes).

Comment: then you have to build the string for the formula with these variables. Sth. like `"=(([@[UTM X]]-" & varD2 & ")^2+([@[UTM Y]]-" & varE1 & ")^2)^0.5/1000"`

Comment: Thank you, I made a problem out of something which wasn't a problem. My error with this formula occured because of the decimalseparators.

Comment: :-)  As you're new on SO: please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)